# Возникает ошибка при парсинге цены

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть парсер на Python, который парсит магазин Лента. Когда парсер доходит до цены, то почему-то один товар получается спарсить, а другой нет. Если парсить этот товар 
https://lenta.com/catalog/bezalkogolnye-napitki/limonady-i-kvasy/limonady/napitok-bezalkogolnyjj-mirinda-refreshing-osvezh-vkus-apelsina-silnogaz-pet-rossiya-15l/

то цена выводится:

```
112,19
----------------------
59,89
----------------------
```

Если парсить этот товар 
https://lenta.com/catalog/tovary-dlya-detejj/igrushki/konstruktory/konstruktor-lego-movie-poznakomtes-s-korolevojj-mnogolikojj-prekrasnojj-70824-kitajj/

то возникает ошибка:

```
    price_1_rub = soup.find('span', class_='sku-price__integer').get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


list_with_category = []
page_link = 'https://lenta.com/catalog/tovary-dlya-detejj/igrushki/konstruktory/konstruktor-lego-movie-poznakomtes-s-korolevojj-mnogolikojj-prekrasnojj-70824-kitajj/'
response = requests.get(page_link)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


price_1_rub = soup.find('span', class_='sku-price__integer').get_text(strip=True)
price_1_rub = price_1_rub.replace("&nbsp;", " ")
price_1_kop = soup.find('small', class_='sku-price__fraction').get_text(strip=True)
price_1_kop = price_1_kop.replace("&nbsp;", " ")

price_2_rub = soup.find('div', class_='sku-price sku-price--primary sku-prices-block__price').find('span', class_='sku-price__integer').get_text(strip=True)
price_2_rub = price_2_rub.replace("&nbsp;", " ")
price_2_kop = soup.find('div', class_='sku-price sku-price--primary sku-prices-block__price').find('small', class_='sku-price__fraction').get_text(strip=True)
price_2_kop = price_2_kop.replace("&nbsp;", " ")
```

Не пойму, классы одинаковые, но где-то ошибка возникает, а где-то нет. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Вот первый: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот второй:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверь селектор, наверное оформлен другим классом

Comment: Приложил 2 скриншота к основному сообщению. Можно заметить, что они одинаковы

Comment: Нбсп тут не проблема, а вот ==$0

Comment: А что ==$0 означает?

Comment: Не, тоже не то..

Comment: Попробовал вывести весь html код всей страницы от первого товара, потом от второго. Удивитесь, но у второго товара вообще нет ни цены, ничего. Как будто вообще другая страница

Comment: И таких товаров "неработающих", много, одна страница работает, другая - нет

Comment: Значит грузится по апи позднее. Первая в кеше SSR, а та собирается онлайн

Comment: Дело в том, что пишу через впн, так как лента МОМЕНТАЛЬНО банит по ip. Но как-то раз и без впн заработало, но цена всё равно не отображается

Comment: Почему выводит None даже при таком обращении? obj = soup.find('span', attrs = {'class':'sku-price__integer'})

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```py
price_tag = soup.find('div', class_='sku-prices-block__item--primary')
if price_tag:
    price_int_tag = price_tag.find('span', class_='sku-price__integer')
    if price_int_tag:
        price_int = price_int_tag.text.strip()

    price_fract_tag = price_tag.find('small', class_='sku-price__fraction')
    if price_fract_tag:
        price_fract = price_fract_tag.text.strip()
else:
    print('Товар отсутствует')
```

> Единственная проблема, что у меня, когда открываю Вашу вторую ссылку, цена в браузере не отображается. Но так как я выше написал, должно работать для тех карточек, где цена есть, а где ее нет, не будет выдавать ошибку